# awk load one file into array, test against another file

Tags: bash, awk

I have two files:

seqs.fa:

```
>seq000007;size=72768;
ACTGTGAG
>seq000010;size=53132;
GTAAGATC
GAATTCTT
>seq00045;size=40321;
ACCCATTT
...
```

numbers.txt

```
72768
53132
```

my desired output would be the lines from the first file that match a number from the second file:

```
>seq000007;size=72768;
>seq000010;size=53132;
```

I attempted to use `awk`, but it only returns lines matching the first number:

```
awk -F"\n" -v RS=">" 'NR==FNR{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) A[$i]; next} END {for (header in A) {if ( match(header,$1) ) {print header}}}'  seqs.fa numbers.txt

seq000007;size=72768;
seq072768;size=1;
```

Why is awk only looping through the "header" array for the first line in numbers.txt? And, if this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), is there a better way to accomplish this goal?

Answer (score 2):

after fixing the typo in your numbers file

```
$ awk -F'=|;' 'NR==FNR{a[$1]; next}; $3 in a' numbers.txt seqs.fa

>seq000007;size=72768;
>seq000010;size=53132;
```

Comment: thanks, edited question to remove typo. this gives the desired output. any ideas why my awk command above doesn't work?

Comment: you have to match $1 in header not the other way around, but it's an inefficient approach.

Comment: I think that's what I'm doing, the call is `match(string, regex)` (unlike match functions I'm used to in python) [source](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~oostr102/docs/nawk/nawk_92.html)

Comment: right, perhaps it's your record structure then.  In your second file there will be only one record.

Answer (score 0):

In this special case you can use GNU grep like this:

```
grep -F -f numbers.txt seqs.fa
```

The option `-f filename` uses all the patterns found in `filename` for the search. The options `-F` tells grep, that the patterns are simple fixed strings.

Comment: note that this will match any occurrence of sub strings in the file.