# use a modified version of each line of a text file as argument in a sed command (bash)

Tags: bash, text-processing

I need to extract all text between two strings from file1. The first string is each line of file2 and the second string is always "Lambda". However, I don't know how to state each string of file2 in my sed command. Also, I need to remove a ">" at the beginning of each line of file2 in order to match the contents of file1:

example file1:

```
some_text1

random text

Lambda

some_text2

random text

Lambda

some_text3

random text

Lambda
```

example file2:

```
>some_text1
>some_text3
```

I´ve come up with this incomplete command for 1 line:

```
sed -n '/**line from file2, without ">" at the beginning**/,/^Lambda/p' file1
```

And, although incomplete, this would be my idea for a loop (this does not include removing the >, which I also need in the command):

```
for line in file1; do sed -n '/$line/,/^Lambda/p' file1; done
```

Example output (note that some_text2 is not present since it isn't on file2:

```
some_text1

random text

Lambda
some_text3

random text

Lambda
```

What can I do?

Comment: Running a separate copy of `sed` per line is _very_ slow, to the point that I would generally recommend a completely different tool (to let you process your whole file in a single pass). It should be possible to write an `awk` script that reads the first line into an array, and then compares each line of the second file against that array, f/e.

Comment: ...you might find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37014532/awk-load-one-file-into-array-test-against-another-file as a good place to start.

Comment: BTW -- `/$line/` matches the `$line` content as a regex _anywhere inside_ a given line. If you expect the values to be matched _as exact text_ (instead of a regex) for the _entire_ line, that permits a much easier, more efficient implementation than the one my answer gave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running multiple copies of `sed` for this is quite inefficient. The below is an awk script that only needs to read `file1` a single time, no matter how long `file2` is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
awk '
  BEGIN   { in_block=0 }
  NR==FNR { array[substr($0, 2)]=1; next }
  in_block == 0 {
    for (item in array) {
      if ($0 ~ item) {
        in_block=1
        print($0)
        next
      }
    }
  }
  in_block == 1 { print }
  in_block == 1 && /^Lambda/ { in_block=0 }
' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more efficiently with `sed` by creating a single pattern that matches all of the strings in file2, and then running it just once on file1. With your example, the pattern would be something like `(some_text1|some_text3)` (although this is in "extended" regex syntax, so you need to use `sed -E` with it). Something like this:

```
lines=$(sed -n 's/^>//p' file2)    # This just reads in the lines with > removed
pattern="(${lines//$'\n'/|})"      # This actually converts them to a regex pattern
sed -En "/${pattern}/,/^Lambda/ p" file1    # Extract all matching ranges
```

Note that if you want to require the string from file2 to match the entire line, not just somewhere in the line, you'd use:

```
pattern="^(${lines//$'\n'/|})\$"    # The ^ and $ anchor to the beginning & end of line
```

Also, be aware that if the lines from file2 contain any regex metacharacters, they'll be treated as their regex meanings; if you want them to be treated as strictly literal strings, you'll need to preprocess them to escape the shell metacharacters. If they contain `/`, that'll also need to be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` in a loop is mostly bad practice. You may consider using the version below, which creates first `sed` commands (using `sed` itself!), then calls the `sed` to process those commands:

```
 sed -n -f <(sed           \
     -e 's/.//'            \
     -e 's/[]\/*.[]/\\&/g' \
     -e 's%.*%/^&$/,/^Lambda$/p%' file2) file1
```

You may want to omit the `-e 's/[]\/*.[]/\\&/g'` portion if it is guaranteed that the file2 doesn't contain any of `[]\/*.` characters. Note that the `<(...)` expression is *process substitution* in `bash`; it appears as a file containing the output of the command between parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
{mawk/mawk2/gawk} 'BEGIN { FS = "^[>]"; FN = ARGV[--ARGC];     
        
        while (getline < FN) { lookupL[$2]++ }; 
        close(FN);

        FN = ARGV[ARGC] = ""; 
        FS = "^Lambda";
    } { 
        match($0, /[[:graph:]]+/); 

       if (substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH) in lookupL) { 

           do { print; 
                if (NF>1) {break} 

           } while (getline); 
       }
   }' file1 file2
```

size of file2 shouldn't be much of an issue unless you're talking more than 2 GB-ish.

Comment: Assuming that the search line will always be a full match? That fits the OP's sample data (and certainly improves efficiency), but not their original program logic; it would be good to get a direct answer from them with respect to whether the difference is intentional.

Comment: @charles : i made some mods just off top of my head last night haven't had chance to actually test against it.